# Android: Quick web requests

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, http-get

For my application I need to have the latest data from an webpage that is hosted on a server on my local network.

So I request the latest page with a `HTTP GET` and when the data is received, I send another request.

With my current implementation I reach around the 100 - 120 ms per request. Is there a possibility to make this quicker because it's the same url that is requested.

For example keep the connection open to the page and grep the latest data without setting up a new connection?

This page is around the 900-1100 bytes.

HTTP get code:

```
public static String makeHttpGetRequest(String stringUrl) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setReadTimeout(300);
        con.setConnectTimeout(300);
        con.setDoOutput(false);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        return readStream(con.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException when setting up connection: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Reading inputstream

```
private static String readStream(InputStream in) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        String line = "";
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException when reading InputStream: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return total.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know there isn't an implementation like you are asking for. I've been dealing a lot with http requests and the best thing you can do is your code. There is another thing which need some attention...your connection maybe slow and depending on that connection time can be more or in some cases which I've been dealing a lot the connection's timeout isn't enough big, but that's server problem.

In my opinion you should use what you have now.